# Populating newly created fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, feature-class

In ArcGIS, i created a new field in my shapefile table and would like to type names there, but cannot.
what do I need to do in order to edit the field?

Comment: If you want to edit the attributes, you need to start an edit session. Or do you want to edit the field itself (name, type, length, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like you haven't enabled the editing mode.
in the table of contents, right click on the layer you want to edit, and select start editing.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the editor tab Customize --> Toolbars --> Editor. From the editor tab, click Editor, then choose start editing. From inside the attribute table you can change the text. When you are finished you will want to save and stop your edits to make them permanent.

Answer (score 0):

First add the Editor toolbar if you haven't already

[image]

Then select the "Start Editing" option on the Editor toolbar dropdown menu

[image]

Make sure to save your edits and end the edit session once you have added the values you need.